# LoRA Embedding Layer is not training properly

Tags: large-language-model

so I know there was a similar question like it. But I am facing a problem
So, I not only want to update the layer, but also update the embedding layer. So for it I use
modules_to_save=["embed_tokens"]

but after training there should be weight change between base model embed_tokens_weight and modules_to_save Embedding weight. But when I check on their mean this is 0, that means it didn't update my embedding layer weight but, it updated the layers weight. So, I guess somehow my embedding layer is not connecting or participating in training.
`merged_model_f_n.base_model.model.model.lm_head.original_moduleSS.weight-merged_model_f_n.base_model.model.model.lm_head.modules_to_save.default.weight`

```
tensor([[0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        ...,
        [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.]], device='cuda:0', dtype=torch.float16,
       grad_fn=<SubBackward0>)
```

```
PeftModel(
  (base_model): LoraModel(
    (model): PeftModelForCausalLM(
      (base_model): LoraModel(
        (model): MistralForCausalLM(
          (model): MistralModel(
            (embed_tokens): ModulesToSaveWrapper(
              (original_module): Embedding(67840, 4096)
              (modules_to_save): ModuleDict(
                (default): Embedding(67840, 4096)
              )
            )
```

Will be happy to accept any suggestion. Thanks